# Children's Sci-Fi novel 1980s, another planet with moth-like creatures and glass-like grass

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, space-colonization, planets

I'm trying to figure out the title of a book I read as a child -- probably around 1988 -- aimed at 9-10 year olds.  The story had to do with people leaving Earth and they were only able to take one personal item with them each.  I remember one person bringing a biology book -- which was helpful.  When they arrived at the new planet, there was glass-like grass that burned funny colors and strange stones around that turned out to be eggs for some beautiful moth-like creatures.  If it helps, this was a reading assignment given to me in the 5th grade in the United States.  Any ideas on what book this might have been?

Answer (score 8):

I feel silly having posted this question earlier, but now I've found the answer.   I had help from some friends from Facebook finding the answer.  The book is called The Green Book by Jill Paton Walsh.

Comment: Don't forget that you can come back and click the gray checkmark on the left to mark this question as solved! :)