# Story Identification: colonists on a planet where the wheat is crystalline

Tags: story-identification

I read a story back in the early 90s about a group of colonists who landed on a planet where the wheat (or wheat-like equivalent) is some kind of crystalline plant. The colonists face starvation until one of them figures out how to process the wheat.

I think it was by Asimov but so far I haven't found it by looking for his works.

I also cannot remember if it was a novel or a short story.

Comment: duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66713/childrens-sci-fi-novel-1980s-another-planet-with-moth-like-creatures-and-glass (which has OP-provided unaccepted answer)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is "[The Green Book](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/252262.The_Green_Book)", a 1986 novel by Jill Paton Walsh

It features crystalline plants (which you can see on the book cover) and a starvation theme;

> Refugees from the dying planet Earth, they, along with
> other ships, have been sent into space in the hope that some of them
> will survive to continue the human race. But the success of Shine
> remains doubtful as crops fail and provisions brought from Earth
> dwindle.
>
> Even the excitement surrounding the hatching of the giant
> moth people from the "boulders" in Boulder Valley doesn't make the
> group forget the hopelessness of the situation. **It isn't until Pattie
> and her sister Sarah make an important discovery that survival becomes
> a certainty.**

The book contains a couple of quite vivid descriptions of the vegetation:

> One morning when we woke up they were all sick, lying in a heap in a
> corner of their hutch, with sad cloudy eyes. And by the next day they
> were all dead. Sarah said they died of homesickness; Father thought
> they might have caught some kind of virus; most people thought they
> had been killed by eating the crystalline plants. The chickens were
> all right; and they had eaten only Earth-grown grain.

Eventually, the children realise that despite the grains being like glass beads, they can be crushed and ground like flour:

> But Sarah said, "I'm going to try, I'm going to try, I'm going to
> try!" She stole a handful of the glass beads, and rubbed them between
> two stones, and they fell easily into a dry white powder that smelled
> good. She sent Pattie for a ladle of lake water, and mixed a dough,
> and rolled it out thin, and made a pancake, and cooked it on the fire.
> Then, when it looked done, she broke it into four pieces, and gave one
> to Pattie and one to Joe, and bit into one herself, leaving Father's
> share in the pan.
>
> Oh, it tasted good! We ate it in three bites.

[image]

Comment: That definitely sounds like it. Not Asimov. No wonder I couldn't find it. Thanks.