# Book that starts with humanity narrowly escaping the death of the sun consuming the Earth

Tags: story-identification, books, soft-sci-fi

The book starts with humanity narrowly escaping the death of the sun consuming the Earth. All the humans are only allowed to bring few possessions with them so a little girl brings a notebook and starts a diary about the adventure.

Then they get to a planet with glass-like wheat and build huts and stuff. A large rock formation turns out to be eggs for an alien species and they hatch. By the end of the book the aliens come back to lay their eggs and many drown and the villagers forget all their stories and legends so they read the little girl's diary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *[The Green Book](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/252262.The_Green_Book)*, a 1986 novel by Jill Paton Walsh.

> Pattie and her family are among the last refuees to flee a dying Earth in an old spaceship. And when the group finally lands on the distant planet which is to be their new home, it seems that the four-year journey has been success. But as they begin to settle this shining world, they discover that the colony is in serious jeopardy. With supplies dwindling, Pattie and her sister decide to take the one chance that might make life possible on Shine.

To quote from [a time I answered this before](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79076/what-diary-style-book-has-a-family-flee-destruction-of-earth-by-exploding-sun-an/173134#173134):

> Indeed, the wheat comes out crystalline and is poisonous to the humans and livestock. The settlers survive on rations, but are close to running out. The moth people hatch from what was originally thought to be a hill of boulders and they eventually return to those round objects.
>
> The children realize that the wheat can be eaten if it's ground up first if I recall correctly. I don't remember how they figured that out.
>
> And yes, the girl has been writing up the history of the story. Due to storage limits, everyone was allowed one book (later in the book, it's established that there are a lot of duplicates, and those who brought a unique book charge high in barter for the privilege of borrowing it). Her siblings teased her unmercifully when they first set off because she brought a blank book, but of course, it turns out she's been writing the first new book of the planet.